# Corrupt SharePoint 2013 Server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error

My SharePoint server has multiple errors and issue with services that I have spent many hours trying to solve.

I am thinking as an alternative, could I remove the server and just add a new one?

I have 1 SharePoint server and 1 SQL server hosting the DB's in my farm. What I want to do if possible is to remove the corrupt SharePoint server from the farm and build a new one add it into the farm and carry on where I left off so no user data is lost.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Here is a [link](http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint-administration/simple-guide-moving-sharepoint-content-databases-new-server) to a site that should help. It just sounds like a database migration to me.

Comment: thank you ill use this guide.

one thing i wanted to try was keep the existing sql database server and just add a new SharePoint server to the farm to try and fix the issues caused by the corrupt SP server, after removing the old one would this get messy? perhaps its cleaner to just build a new environment and migrate the content DB over what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Would someone please put this post as a comment?  Don't have the rep to do so yet, and this is only in reply to his comment.  Thanks!

I have never personally migrated servers, so I'm not sure of how messy something like this is.  I wouldn't want to give you the wrong answer, but I would imagine just replacing the sharepoint server and keeping the SQL one should be easier than a new environment.

Comment: its in a test environment so there is no risk to production data i am wanting to find the best method before i role it out in production i can try both i guess .

Answer (score 0):

Two things i would do.

1. you can run the config wizard on the SharePoint server without disconnecting and keep the defaults (this server will host the Central admin.). Once config wizard completed successfully then test it.
2. if above failed, then i would build the 2nd server with the same build level as my current is.

   - Now Run the Config wizard on new server and join the existing farm.
   - Now move all the services on the new server i.e search UPA, MMS etc(what ever you configured).
   - you can do this from manage services on server
   - once everything move to new server then disconnect the existing(old corrupt server).

I am sure if you disconnect the existing server without adding another then you end to rebuild new farm.

Comment: "you can run the config wizard on the SharePoint server without disconnecting and keep the defaults (this server will host the Central admin.). Once config wizard completed successfully then test it", so do this on the corrupt server? or do this on the new server? could you give any more info? Thankyou for the reply

Comment: This should be on corrupted server n before brining any server into the farm.this an effort to fix the problem

Comment: yes i have tried this it never worked sadly. i am going to follow point 2 i am still quite new to SharePoint what would i need to move to the new server? how would i move the web application so its hosted on the new server? thank you